# Doubts about quark confinement, the pole mass and the quark gluon plasma

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement, quark-gluon-plasma

I have seen written a few times that the notion of a pole mass for a quark contradicts the quark confinement picture and that non-perturbatively it is expected that the quark pole mass be infinite. Nevertheless, I have also heard about the quark gluon plasma where quarks and gluons are deconfined. This means that at least in some situations speaking about deconfined quark masses does make sense and that the argument pointing out that the pole mass should be infinite for quarks because of confinement trembles. How does one reconcile these ideas? Is the pole mass expected to be infinite or not?